# How to: AngularJS http GET request to Laravel CRUD resource controller

Tags: angularjs, laravel, http, laravel-5

I have been trying to get a response from my laravel resource controller through a http GET request from angularJS. Please let me know what i'm doing wrong. My console.log() does not show anything.

Web.php file has the following route

```
Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');
```

I have a laravel resource(CRUD) controller named CommentsController which has the function.

```
public function show(Comment $comment) {
    //show comement
    $articleComments = DB::table('comments')->where('id', $comment->articleID);
    if (!$articleComments->isEmpty()) {
        //return Json as response
        return response()->json($articleComments);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'Not Found!']);
    }
}
```

This is what my laravel route list looks like for comments

[Laravel route:list for comments controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZu1j.jpg)

I want to use AngularJS http GET request to retrieve comments for an article. This is my AngularJS code.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
          $scope.loadComments = function(id){
            $http.get("comments",{
              params: {
                'articleID': id
              }})
            .then(function(response) {
                //First function handles success
                console.log(response.data)
            }, function(response) {
                //Second function handles error
                console.log(response.data)
            });
          }
      });
```

I have included the CSRF protection tag as well

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

My html button that initiated the loadComments

```
<button type="button" id="getArticleId" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="comment button" ng-click="loadComments({{$key->id}})">
```

My response looks like

[Chrome network analysis header output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXEjE.jpg)

Comment: In order to help people provide answers, you may wish to include information about the behavior/response you're expecting versus what you're actually observing or what is "wrong".

Comment: Sorry made the edit: my issue is that the console.log does not show anything (error or data).

Comment: What calls loadComments?

Comment: loadComments is the html button with ng-click function. Added it to the question post above.

Comment: Are you using dependency injection? Because `public function show(Comment $comment) {` does not work out of the box right?

Comment: [SOLVED] - I changed the GET request. Remove the param and change the  GET as following.
$http.get('comments\' + 'id') -- followed by the rest of the code.